# Pattern matching and substring replacement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to do pattern matching and substring replacement in PostgreSQL with a "select-case-when-then-update-query".
Example:

```
tableA

field1               |field2          | field3
---------------------+----------------+-----------
(varchar)bla abla 123|(varchar)abla   |(varchar)123
(varchar)blub 456    |(varchar)blub   |(varchar)456
```

remaining string in field1 after performing the substring replacement should be "bla" in row 1 and "blub 456" in row 2 (see Note below):

```
tableA

field1               |field2          | field3
---------------------+----------------+-----------
(varchar)bla         |(varchar)abla   |(varchar)123
(varchar)blub 456    |(varchar)blub   |(varchar)456
```

So, I would like to update field1 if the following condition is true:

Pseudocode:

```
if string from field2 and/or string from field3  is substring of field1 
then replace substring field2, field3 from field1 if remaining string in field1 > 0
```

Note: If there is no string or token left in field1 after substring removal the string should not be touched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't disclosed what to do with whitespaces or what to do with overlapping substrings.  Anyhow, something like this could help:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET field1 = replace(replace(field1, field2, ''), field3, '')
WHERE replace(replace(field1, field2, ''), field3, '') <> '';
```

There is no pattern to match, simply replace a string (in an other column) with nothing.  You don't have to care about substrings as if the value of `field2` does not occur in `field1` then it won't be replaced.

See this on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/53649/3).

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this is great to start with. Thank you!